# Implementing OAuth protocol in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oauth

I'm looking for an open source library that implements the OAuth protocol , I need the server side implementation . Say I have a Social network system , and I want to give my users an OAuth abiliy to my API , like facebook.

Do you have any suggestion , sure examples .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few Java libraries list here,

http://oauth.net/code/

You should use the first one. It's the only one with server support. You can find an example,

http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/example/oauth-provider/

You might want also look at OAuth 2.0,

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-02

Which greatly simplifies OAuth flow and you don't really need a library to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for your help . One more thing , my project is built on EJB2.1 , so , what you recommend , to make session bean that manages the oauth-provider or can use it as is , I need to make some operations with the DB , so I need to make some omdifications in the code.

Thanks ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://github.com/apifest/apifest-oauth20
It's written in Java and uses Netty as a server. As a storage, it currently uses Hazelcast(by default), MongoDB or Redis. Also, you can easily add another backend storage.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/oauth/ is the reference library, or there's also http://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to implement oauth server using a Java Spring technologies.

Here is  an implementation using Spring Boot.

https://github.com/dsyer/sparklr-boot